# Rearranging multiple Pivot Table Columns using Macros

Tags: excel, vba

Please dont close this question. I havent got a solution and its not a duplicate question, please understand the query.

I have a pivot table that has multiple columns, I want to **dynamically** rearrange the columns .

Sample pivot column header

| Row Label | 1 day | 10 days | 11 days | 13 days | 17 days | 2 days | 21 days | 3 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I want to rearrange this in ascending order. like this

| Row Label | 1 day | 2 days | 3 days | 10 days | 11 days | 13 days | 17 days | 21 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Points to note:

1. the pivot table is made **dynamically**
2. **No assurity on column names remaining the same, it can change according to data set.**
3. Data set cant be changed, cant edit it to 01 days,02 days etc.

Additionally, if this was a normal table/column we would have gone with a header sorting function (Code given below), can something of the same be applied here??

Specifically, storing values in an array, and using that to sort the pivot table column header??

```
Function Reorder_Columns()
  
Dim ColumnOrder As Variant, ndx As Integer, Found As Range, counter As Integer, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate
    
    ColumnOrder = Array("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4")
counter = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
For ndx = LBound(ColumnOrder) To UBound(ColumnOrder)
    Set Found = Rows("1:1").Find(ColumnOrder(ndx), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        If Found.Column <> counter Then
            Found.EntireColumn.Cut
            Columns(counter).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next ndx
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

**EDIT**
**Answers given by Both Raymond Wu and Tim Williams are perfect for this with difference in time for each being .04 seconds.**

Comment: Why not sort the column field. . You may not need VBA for that.. If VBA is must try recording the sort column field. Then you won't need to loop through all the fields.

Comment: Have you tried to adopt the code to your purpose?

Comment: For sorting column fields of a Pivot table in VBA    `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Column Labels").AutoSort xlAscending, "Column Labels"`.. Also, the code in the question doesn't look like for Pivot

Comment: I believe he can't use AutoSort because it will end up like what he shown in his Sample pivot column header.

Comment: Bottom of this page has something similar to what you want: https://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-sorting.html

Comment: @RaymondWu True :) .. .. May be it can be solved if added 0 to single digits.. Like 01 Day, 02, Days, 11 Days

Comment: @Naresh Can't be done too, I think someone advised him before (in a deleted question) and he said he can't change the data.

Comment: You can change the position of a pivot item like: `Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("YourField").PivotItems("YourItem").Position = 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example including the sorting part:

```vb
Sub PTCustomFieldSort()

    Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem, arr(), i As Long, pos As Long
    
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Col2")
    
    'get an array of values for sorting
    ReDim arr(1 To pf.PivotItems.Count)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = pf.PivotItems(i).Name
    Next i
    SortSpecial arr, "SortVal"  'sort the array
    
    pt.ManualUpdate = True
    pos = 1
    'loop and order as wanted...
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        Set pi = pf.PivotItems(arr(i))
        If pi.Visible Then
            pi.Position = pos
            pos = pos + 1
        End If
    Next i
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    pt.RefreshTable

End Sub



'Sorts an array using some specific translation defined in `func`
Sub SortSpecial(list, func As String)
    Dim First As Long, Last As Long, i As Long, j As Long, tmp, arrComp()
    First = LBound(list)
    Last = UBound(list)
    'fill the "compare array...
    ReDim arrComp(First To Last)
    For i = First To Last
        arrComp(i) = Application.Run(func, list(i))
    Next i
    'now sort by comparing on `arrComp` not `list`
    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If arrComp(i) > arrComp(j) Then
                tmp = arrComp(j)          'swap positions in the "comparison" array
                arrComp(j) = arrComp(i)
                arrComp(i) = tmp
                tmp = list(j)             '...and in the original array
                list(j) = list(i)
                list(i) = tmp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Function SortVal(v)
    SortVal = Val(v) ' "1 day" --> 1, "11 days" --> 11 etc
End Function
```

Comment: my apologies, I had updated in the question rather than in the comments for each anwser, both approaches work and are comparable, time wise, to each other with a time difference of 0.4 seconds that could have been human error.

Answer (score 1):

Modified from the code sample given in the link posted by Tim Williams, adapt the code below to your purpose:

```
Sub SortPT()
    Dim rngSort As Variant
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim lCount As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    rngSort = Array("1 day", "2 days", "3 days", "10 days", "11 days") 'Adapt to your column headers in sequence
    
    Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1") 'Change to correct Worksheet and PivotTable name
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("1 day") 'Change to the correct PivotField name
    lCount = 1
    
    pt.ManualUpdate = True
    With pf
      .AutoSort xlManual, pf.SourceName
      Dim i As Long
      For i = LBound(rngSort) To UBound(rngSort)
        Set pi = Nothing
        Set pi = .PivotItems(rngSort(i))
          If Not pi Is Nothing Then
            If pi.Visible = True Then
              pi.Position = lCount
              lCount = lCount + 1
            End If
          End If
      Next i
    End With
    
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
    pt.RefreshTable
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: my apologies,  I had updated the feedback in the question rather than in the comments for each answer, both approaches work and are comparable, time wise, to each other with a time difference of 0.4 seconds that could have been human error.

Comment: @Allwyn All's good! IMO Tim's answer is better in the sense that you don't have to pre-define the sort array as it is done automatically from the extracted array of `PivotItems`.