# Color Pivot Table data depending on column header compared to row data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot tables that have no of days as columns and category as rows,

**EDIT:-** I want to highlight 4 conditions

1. all Values that fall under the condition online and are equal to 2 days (in one color "Orange")
2. all Values that fall under the condition online and are greater than 2 days (in one color "Red")
3. all cells that are under any header greater than 5 days (in another color "Yellow")
4. any time the headers are 5 days or more, then the headers themselves are highlighted in "Yellow"

[image: PFB image for table]

thus I want to highlight cell values based on Column values(condition based greater than 6 days)
and row values(highlight rows that are online)

Is this possible?? in vba or excel??

Output that I am gunning for is as follows.

[image]

Comment: How about showing up at your previous question and providing a bit of feedback on the answers there?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660937/rearranging-multiple-pivot-table-columns-using-macros

Comment: @TimWilliams, I made the mistake of updating the feedback in the question rather than in each individual answers. both of the answers worked, with .4 seconds difference between each.. can be a mistake of setting the timer, I havent selected answers for the same reason. as both works well

Comment: @Tim Williams any suggestions on this issue??

Comment: Would help to add an "after" screenshot so it's clearer what you mean.

Comment: @Tim Williams, have edited the conditions & have added an after screenshot for clarity. Please check

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Could you provide an example workbook with that pivot table?

Comment: @TimWilliams please check the file here:    https://www.filemail.com/d/ttnzpwlovubxyks

Comment: @TimWilliams any Feedback??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you try this out yourself first and we help you fix your code, but since this was a useful exercise for me...

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim pt As PivotTable, pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem, d, clr As Long
    Dim rngTwoDays As Range, rngFiveDays As Range, rwOnline As Range, c As Range
    
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
    pt.TableRange1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone 'uncolor
    
    'some code for figuring out what's what in terms of ranges etc
    Debug.Print "*** Row Fields ***"
    PrintInfo pt.RowFields
    Debug.Print "*** Column Fields***"
    PrintInfo pt.ColumnFields
    'done figuring out...
    
    'Start coloring
    
    ' x days labels >=5days
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("WC")
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        d = Val(pi.Name) 'days number only
        If d >= 5 Then pi.LabelRange.Resize(2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        If d = 5 Then Set rngFiveDays = pi.DataRange 'for next block
        If d = 2 Then Set rngTwoDays = pi.DataRange  'for next block
    Next pi
    
    'the rest
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Order Category")
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        For Each c In pi.DataRange.Cells
            If c.Value > 0 Then
                clr = -1 'reset
                Select Case pi.Name
                    Case "Online"
                        If c.Column >= rngTwoDays.Column Then
                            clr = IIf(Not Application.Intersect(c, rngTwoDays) Is Nothing, _
                                      XlRgbColor.rgbOrange, vbRed)
                        End If
                    Case Else
                        If c.Column >= rngFiveDays.Column Then clr = vbYellow
                End Select
                If clr > -1 Then c.Interior.Color = clr
            End If
        Next c
    Next pi
End Sub

'utility sub for printing field information
Sub PrintInfo(fldsCol As Object)
    Dim pf As PivotField, pi As PivotItem
    For Each pf In fldsCol
        Debug.Print pf.Position, pf.Name
        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
            Debug.Print , pi.Position, pi.Name, pi.LabelRange.Address, pi.DataRange.Address
        Next pi
    Next pf
End Sub
```

Comment: I have used your code in a dynamic generation of  13 pivot tables, of which 9 pivot tables have conditions favorable to your code, but only 5 of them have been fully colored, the other 4 has been partially colored.

Comment: am updating the images as an answer to the question

Comment: am updating the debug code also. Please check

Comment: The answer I gave was specific to your posted example - I wouldn't expect it to necessarily work on pivot tables with different layouts...   As for the Debug.Print output - all it does it list out the available row/column fields, their position, and the data range (where in the table the "values" are which correspond to each item under that field), and where the labels are located.  That information you can use in the code to color the areas you want.

Comment: the layout remains the same, things that I have edited in your code, is the pivot table name (have made it dynamic)  & `pt.PivotFields("WC")` this  also I have made it dynamic, by having variables give the pivot name.  The row fields and the column fields remain the same. But for some reason, for certain pivots the `stock values` dont get highlighted. Very curious indeed.  Could you give me some pointers as in what I have to do to adapt this to my scenario??

Comment: Your screenshots only show part of the "non-working" tables, so it's difficult for me to say anything about what the problem is.  Maybe post a new question on one specific table with your modified code and explain exactly where it's going wrong?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845324/color-pivot-table-data-depending-on-row-column-data-values-vba) have posted the question with modified code, please look